# How can I debug C++ pybind11 module with lldb?

Tags: python, c++, lldb, pybind11

I tried to follow the instructions [here](http://johntfoster.github.io/posts/debugging-cc%2B%2B-libraries-called-by-python.html), but I'm getting the `unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual location` warning. Here is what I do exactly. I first compile the code with the `-g` flag:

```
c++ -g -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -undefined dynamic_lookup `python3 -m pybind11 --includes` fractal.cpp -o fractal`python3-config --extension-suffix`
```

Then, I launch python from the command line, which is set to run the system python 3.8.5. I check the `pid` with

```
ps aux | grep -i python
```

In another terminal window, I launch `lldb` and type

```
attach --pid 77352
```

The rest of it goes this way:

```
(lldb) continue
Process 77352 resuming
(lldb) breakpoint set -f fractal.cpp -l 66
Breakpoint 1: no locations (pending).
WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations.
```

What am I missing? Since pybind11 doesn't print errors in the C++ code until the end of the calling python script, I can't just print stuff out to the screen to see where the code breaks down. I would like to be able to go through the code line by line.

I'm on macOS `10.15.5`, if it makes any difference. I also double checked that I'm selecting a valid line in `fractal.cpp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**All you need to do now is to `import` your module now.**

While it's not imported, neither python nor lldb can "know" about existance of your sorce file (fractal.cpp).
After you import it, the `lldb` will immediately react with:

```
1 location added to breakpoint 1
```

And then once you call the function with breakpont in it:

```
Process 8189 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x00000001011af3fa mypylib.cpython-38-darwin.so`add(i=1, j=2) at main.cpp:6:12
   3    namespace py = pybind11;
   4
   5    int add(int i, int j) {
-> 6        return i + j;
   7    }
   8
   9    PYBIND11_MODULE(mypylib, m) {
Target 0: (Python) stopped.
```

Comment: Do I need to somehow import it in `lldb`? Or import it in the python prompt I have running? The latter didn't seem to work.

Comment: You need to cause your module to get loaded into the Python you are debugging, so run the "import" command in the Python.

Comment: Then you can check whether the library was actually loaded by interrupting the execution in lldb with `process interrupt`, and running `image list`.  Is your new dylib in the list?  Is it where you expect it to be (maybe there's another one without debug info?).  You can run `source info -f fractal.cpp` to see if it has source info....

Comment: Ok, it worked! I think I was getting the `pid` wrong as well. I did `os.getpid()` instead, as there were a billion python processes running (thanks to neovim). Would you like to add the import part in more detail in the answer so that it's clearer for others who may have the same question?