# pybind11 module debugging with lldb , import killed but not with lldb

Tags: lldb, pybind11

I am new to debugging pybind11 modules with lldb, hope my question will make sense

I am trying to debug a pybind11 module with lldb. I get the error:

```
Python 3.9.17 (main, Jul 23 2023, 14:18:04)
[Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import module_name
[1]    63586 killed     /Users/esalimbe/Desktop/pybind11_sandbox/python3.9/bin/python3.9
```

To debug with lldb. I am using `attach --pid <process id for python>` and them import my module in the python interpreter. (following :  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63248904/how-can-i-debug-c-pybind11-module-with-lldb) )

```
Python 3.9.17 (main, Jul 23 2023, 14:18:04)
[Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import module_name
>>> module_name.__doc__
'This is a test'
>>> module_name.some_fn_in_python(1,2)
3.0
```

Surprisingly I do not get my program killed when using lldb, and am a bit lost how to debug it.

I expect the program not to crash if on lldb it does not.